# batch file to delete folders

Tags: batch

I am trying to get a batch file to delete folders and their contents. The batch file deletes all the files contained in the folders, BUT the folders still remain.

```
del /s /f /q C:\Users\GT\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent\CompletedDL\*.*
for /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b C:\Users\GT\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent\CompletedDL\') do rd /s /q 
C:\Users\GT\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent\CompletedDL\%%f
```

can anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: To make your code easier to read, could you please indent it with 4 spaces? https://superuser.com/editing-help#code

Comment: When you run the command and it gets to the `rd` command, what is the message you see when it runs? What happens if you try to delete one of those folders manually, do you get an error?

Comment: No messages are displayed.  I run the batch file from Task Manager.   I dont know very much about coding etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's not working in your script, but this should work:

```
del /f /q "%appdata%\uTorrent\CompletedDL\*.*"
for /d %%d in ("%appdata%\uTorrent\CompletedDL\*.*") do rmdir /s /q "%%d"
```

The `/d` switch searches for subdirectories which are then removed with `rmdir`. I also added double quotes, because rmdir would break if the path contains spaces.

The `/s` switch in the `del` command is not neccesary, because `rmdir /s` will remove files as well.

Comment: That did the trick thankyou very much !!!